# start.sh dosen't work in agent2d robocup

Tags: simulation, opensuse, robocup

I have a 64-bit opensuse os and I'm trying to simulate robocup in it. when I go to step for run start.sh file in agent2d, it gives me an error.
error:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.026/0.026/0.026/0.000 ms
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_player: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample_coach: error while loading shared libraries: librcsc_agent.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but sample_player is in src folder and sample_coach is in it too.
Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's my answer

```
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Just write it in the terminal that gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

https://osdn.net/projects/rctools/releases/p3777
Installing librcsc

```
$ cd librcsc-x.x.x/
```

Run the commands:

Note: If you have permission problems in the first step, instead of ./configure execute sh ./configure.

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```